# Need Help Understanding the "Call Gate" Sequence for the STM32's Firewall

Tags: c, stm32, firewall

I am trying to use the STM32(l412kb)'s firewall according to to page 146 of this [reference manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/02/35/09/0c/4f/f7/40/03/DM00083560.pdf/files/DM00083560.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00083560.pdf). I understand that to initialise the firewall, you need to set the base address and the length of the segment you want to protect. You then enable the firewall by clearing the FWDIS (firewall disabled) bit in the SYSCFG register.

However I do not understand how the firewall can be opened to execute code. From my understanding there are three words located at the first three 32-bit addresses of the code segment. The first word is a dummy word. The second and third words are two specific 32 bit words called the 'call gate'.

My questions are:

1. At what point were these 3 words created?
2. Do i need to put in some extra code to open the gate?
3. What are these two call-gate words?
4. The reference manual mentions that the dummy word is skipped to the 2nd and 3rd words. How do I ensure this happens?

   5. To protect the SRAM, the address of the memory location to protect must be known. How do I know where in RAM the data I want to protect will be held?

Or are these all automatic hardware actions.

Many thanks in advance for your help,

Harry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. At what point were these 3 words created?

They are created by the compiler and linker, and written into the on-chip flash.

> 2. Do i need to put in some extra code to open the gate?

No. The firewall will be opened by jumping to the second word.

> 3. What are these two call-gate words?

Thumb(-2) machine code instructions at the beginning of the protected function. They must be fetched sequentially, it means that there should be no branch instructions in the second word.

I'd just fill the first and second words with 4 `NOP` instructions, and put the protected function directly after.

> 4. The reference manual mentions that the dummy word is skipped to the 2nd and 3rd words. How do I ensure this happens?

Write your code carefully so it doesn't ever attempt to execute or read the first word.

> 5. To protect the SRAM, the address of the memory location to protect must be known. How do I know where in RAM the data I want to protect will be held?

Define a separate section in the linker definition file (`.ld`, `.sct` or `.icf`, depending on the linker used) to put the protected variables in, aligned according to the firewall requirements, then export a symbol at the beginning and one at the end of the section, like it is done in the `.data`, `.bss` and `.heap` sections.